# Using async parallel() to save() changes to two mongoose Schema, it saves, but hangs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I've made changes to two Schema in a `mongoose` in an `express` project, and tried to save them using async's parallel method, and return a new page, and it does save both desired changes, but it hangs and never redirects to the new page.
(I'm quite confused about quite how the `.save()` function returns results.)

```js
async.parallel(
    {
        message: function(callback) {
            message.save(function(callback) {});
        },
        user: function(callback) {
            req.user.save(function(callback) {});
        },
    }, function (err,results) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.redirect('user/' + req.body.receipient);
    }
);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a mongoose issue. It's actually an async code error in the code. You seem to be confused between `async.parallel` callback function you need to call, and `model.save` callback function that you need to provide to mongoose to be called after saving operation

You need to call the callback function of all the calls/methods you are executing under `async.parallel`

```
async.parallel({
    message: function(callback) {
      message.save(function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    },
    user: function(callback) {
      req.user.save(function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    },
  }, function (err,results) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('user/' + req.body.receipient);
  })
```

`Mongoose.save` method returns an only error object if any. [See doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks so much. The callbacks confuse me a lot. Who's going where. What's doing what.